# r: coding dummy variables based-on max value for each month

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to code a new variable called `df$dummy` based-on the max value in `df$var1` for each `df$month`, where the value will be `1` for the max value and `0` for every other value. See reproducible data set:

```
df<- data.frame(date= seq.Date(from = as.Date('2017-01-01'), by= 7, 
                length.out = 20), var1= rnorm(20, 5, 3))

df$month<- as.numeric(strftime(df$date, "%m"))
```

I'm having trouble conceptualizing the conditions for the function. In Excel I would just use the `maxif` function and specific my criteria. My attempt below does not work:

```
df$dummy<- apply(df$var1, MARGIN = 2, 
                 function(x) if_else(max(x) %in% df$month, 1, 0))
```

It returns this error:

```
Error in apply(df$var1, MARGIN = 2, function(x) if_else(max(x) %in% df$month,  : 
dim(X) must have a positive length
```

How do I code this dummy variable? Is there a viable `dplyr` solution using `mutate_if`?

Comment: `ifelse(condition, 1, 0)` is equivalent but much slower than `as.integer(max(x) %in% df$month)`. This is because `FALSE/TRUE` are coded as `0/1`. (Any `condition`, of course.)

Comment: Also, `if_else` is not a base R function, it's a package `dplyr` one. When you use a non-base function start the scripts with a call to `library()` to load the package you need.

Comment: The error comes from the fact that you are applying a function to the 2nd dimension of `df$var1` but `df$var1` is a vector. You do not need `apply`. And I bet that `max(x) %in% df$month` is always `FALSE`, the max of a continuous variable is not an integer with probability `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr`, the key is to use `group_by` to separate the data frame by month. Then, `var1 == max(var1)` will operate within each month, as you want. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
df<- data.frame(date= seq.Date(from = as.Date('2017-01-01'), by= 7, length.out = 20), var1= rnorm(20, 5, 3))
df$month<- as.numeric(strftime(df$date, "%m"))

df <- df %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  mutate(dummy = as.integer(var1 == max(var1))) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 1):

with `data.table` package  it is fairly easy to do it.

```
library(data.table)

df<- data.frame(date= seq.Date(from = as.Date('2017-01-01'), by= 7, 
                 length.out = 20), var1= rnorm(20, 5, 3))

df$month<- as.numeric(strftime(df$date, "%m"))

set.DT(df)
df[,dummy:=ifelse(max(var1)==var1,1,0),month]

## df
##           date      var1 month dummy
##  1: 2017-01-01  2.213981     1     0
##  2: 2017-01-08  1.768855     1     0
##  3: 2017-01-15  4.765936     1     0
##  4: 2017-01-22  3.930655     1     0
##  5: 2017-01-29  6.548077     1     1
##  6: 2017-02-05 -1.489263     2     0
##  7: 2017-02-12  4.448080     2     0
##  8: 2017-02-19  9.734254     2     1
##  9: 2017-02-26  3.322127     2     0
## 10: 2017-03-05  8.023423     3     1
## 11: 2017-03-12  6.915339     3     0
## 12: 2017-03-19  3.563988     3     0
## 13: 2017-03-26  4.393971     3     0
## 14: 2017-04-02  8.361803     4     0
## 15: 2017-04-09  3.636038     4     0
## 16: 2017-04-16  3.804143     4     0
## 17: 2017-04-23 11.269707     4     1
## 18: 2017-04-30  7.024666     4     0
## 19: 2017-05-07 10.771904     5     1
## 20: 2017-05-14  4.877943     5     0
```