# Coding dummy variable based on max value of two groups in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Building off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55197748/r-coding-dummy-variables-based-on-max-value-for-each-month), I'm trying to create the same dummy variable for the maximum value of each group, but instead of just grouping by the month column, I'd like to group on both month and year so I get the maximum value for both, i.e. a dummy for the max value in 1-2017, 2-2017 , etc.

I've created a demo dataset here as well as some code showing the undesired result when I try to group by two columns.

```
df<- data.frame(date= seq.Date(from = as.Date('2017-01-01'), by= 14, length.out = 100), var1= rnorm(20, 5, 3))
df$month<- as.numeric(strftime(df$date, "%m"))
df$year <- as.numeric(strftime(df$date, "%Y"))

df <- df %>%
    group_by(year, month) %>%
    mutate(dummy = as.integer(var1 == max(var1))) %>%
    ungroup
```

When I run this code, this is the output I get.

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(17167L, 17181L, 17195L, 17209L, 
17223L, 17237L, 17251L, 17265L, 17279L, 17293L, 17307L, 17321L, 
17335L, 17349L, 17363L, 17377L, 17391L, 17405L, 17419L, 17433L, 
17447L, 17461L, 17475L, 17489L, 17503L, 17517L, 17531L, 17545L, 
17559L, 17573L, 17587L, 17601L, 17615L, 17629L, 17643L, 17657L, 
17671L, 17685L, 17699L, 17713L, 17727L, 17741L, 17755L, 17769L, 
17783L, 17797L, 17811L, 17825L, 17839L, 17853L, 17867L, 17881L, 
17895L, 17909L, 17923L, 17937L, 17951L, 17965L, 17979L, 17993L, 
18007L, 18021L, 18035L, 18049L, 18063L, 18077L, 18091L, 18105L, 
18119L, 18133L, 18147L, 18161L, 18175L, 18189L, 18203L, 18217L, 
18231L, 18245L, 18259L, 18273L, 18287L, 18301L, 18315L, 18329L, 
18343L, 18357L, 18371L, 18385L, 18399L, 18413L, 18427L, 18441L, 
18455L, 18469L, 18483L, 18497L, 18511L, 18525L, 18539L, 18553L
), class = "Date"), var1 = c(7.610410421533, 4.39838519593849, 
7.29367017299385, 4.65490632032971, 5.98987372646137, 7.89362434824241, 
7.37466247923975, 3.55735383387344, 2.04726523393801, 7.85753545892588, 
8.9757840439474, 3.03010111198631, 8.12870854721674, 4.94313056382185, 
10.3008527572542, 3.38195982516332, 2.38095744572549, 2.33860273928046, 
4.55108829246478, 10.3054094468083, 7.610410421533, 4.39838519593849, 
7.29367017299385, 4.65490632032971, 5.98987372646137, 7.89362434824241, 
7.37466247923975, 3.55735383387344, 2.04726523393801, 7.85753545892588, 
8.9757840439474, 3.03010111198631, 8.12870854721674, 4.94313056382185, 
10.3008527572542, 3.38195982516332, 2.38095744572549, 2.33860273928046, 
4.55108829246478, 10.3054094468083, 7.610410421533, 4.39838519593849, 
7.29367017299385, 4.65490632032971, 5.98987372646137, 7.89362434824241, 
7.37466247923975, 3.55735383387344, 2.04726523393801, 7.85753545892588, 
8.9757840439474, 3.03010111198631, 8.12870854721674, 4.94313056382185, 
10.3008527572542, 3.38195982516332, 2.38095744572549, 2.33860273928046, 
4.55108829246478, 10.3054094468083, 7.610410421533, 4.39838519593849, 
7.29367017299385, 4.65490632032971, 5.98987372646137, 7.89362434824241, 
7.37466247923975, 3.55735383387344, 2.04726523393801, 7.85753545892588, 
8.9757840439474, 3.03010111198631, 8.12870854721674, 4.94313056382185, 
10.3008527572542, 3.38195982516332, 2.38095744572549, 2.33860273928046, 
4.55108829246478, 10.3054094468083, 7.610410421533, 4.39838519593849, 
7.29367017299385, 4.65490632032971, 5.98987372646137, 7.89362434824241, 
7.37466247923975, 3.55735383387344, 2.04726523393801, 7.85753545892588, 
8.9757840439474, 3.03010111198631, 8.12870854721674, 4.94313056382185, 
10.3008527572542, 3.38195982516332, 2.38095744572549, 2.33860273928046, 
4.55108829246478, 10.3054094468083), month = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 
12, 12, 12, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 
9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10), 
    year = c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
    2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
    2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 
    2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
    2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
    2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
    2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
    2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
    2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
    2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
    2020, 2020), dummy = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: You have exactly 1 maximum per month-year combination with this code, what's wrong with it?

Comment: I'd like the maximum within each month-year combination. So I'd want a 1 for the max value in 1-2017, for 2-2017 ,etc.

Comment: If I run your code I get that.. compare aggregate(var1~month+year,data=df,max) with df[df$dummy==1,]

Comment: Your dummy variable labels all the maximum with 1s

Comment: This is really strange, but I am only getting 5 rows where dummy==1.

Comment: No, I just cleared it and am getting the same results as posted above.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it looks like. I don't understand why it works for year and month individually, but not both together.

Comment: Ok I posted something below.. You can just check it and see whether there's anything wrong with your installation.. Extremely weird

Comment: Oh cool, your function solution works. Thank you! I think there was a package clash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I take the data.frame output you provided, and I do the same mutate call, I get a totally different output:

```
df %>% group_by(month,year) %>% mutate(ismax=as.integer(var1==max(var1)))
# A tibble: 100 x 6
# Groups:   month, year [46]
   date        var1 month  year dummy ismax
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
 1 2017-01-01  7.61     1  2017     0     1
 2 2017-01-15  4.40     1  2017     0     0
 3 2017-01-29  7.29     1  2017     0     0
 4 2017-02-12  4.65     2  2017     0     0
 5 2017-02-26  5.99     2  2017     0     1
 6 2017-03-12  7.89     3  2017     0     1
 7 2017-03-26  7.37     3  2017     0     0
 8 2017-04-09  3.56     4  2017     0     1
 9 2017-04-23  2.05     4  2017     0     0
10 2017-05-07  7.86     5  2017     0     0
```

These are my system settings, is the dplyr version too old or did you load another package that clash?

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.8.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2       fansi_0.4.0      zeallot_0.1.0    utf8_1.1.4      
 [5] crayon_1.3.4     assertthat_0.2.1 R6_2.4.0         backports_1.1.5 
 [9] magrittr_1.5     pillar_1.4.2     cli_1.1.0        rlang_0.4.1     
[13] vctrs_0.2.0      glue_1.3.1       purrr_0.3.3      compiler_3.6.1  
[17] pkgconfig_2.0.3  tidyselect_0.2.5 tibble_2.1.3
```

Otherwise you can try this way:

```
myfunc = function(x)as.integer(x$var1==max(x$var1))
df %>% group_by(year,month) %>% do(data.frame(. , ismax = myfunc(.)))
# A tibble: 100 x 6
# Groups:   year, month [46]
   date        var1 month  year dummy ismax
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
 1 2017-01-01  7.61     1  2017     0     1
 2 2017-01-15  4.40     1  2017     0     0
 3 2017-01-29  7.29     1  2017     0     0
 4 2017-02-12  4.65     2  2017     0     0
 5 2017-02-26  5.99     2  2017     0     1
 6 2017-03-12  7.89     3  2017     0     1
 7 2017-03-26  7.37     3  2017     0     0
 8 2017-04-09  3.56     4  2017     0     1
 9 2017-04-23  2.05     4  2017     0     0
10 2017-05-07  7.86     5  2017     0     0
# … with 90 more rows
```